# Replacing text in a textbox, and then adding it to listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, replace, listbox, stringbuilder

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If TextBox11.Text.Contains("https") Then
        TextBox11.Text.Replace("https", "http")
        Debug.WriteLineIf(TextBox11.Text.Contains("http"), "youtube link https replaced with http")
        If TextBox11.Text.Contains("https") Then
            ListBox3.Items.Add(TextBox11.Text)
            Debug.WriteLine("items added to listbox")
        End If
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("items added to listbox(without repalce)")
        ListBox3.Items.Add(TextBox11.Text)
    End If

End Sub
```

so, what i tried to do here was to replace "https" with "https" in textbox11, and then adding it to listbox3, but,it not even replaces the text for some reason,and this is where i need a little bit of help.I know, stringbuilder is good for this,but i don't know how to use it, i only found how to replace a specified text, but not from a whole sentence.

p.s. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Replace method returns a new string with the replaced text. It doesn't work on the same string that you pass in. So you need to reassign the result of Replace

```
TextBox11.Text = TextBox11.Text.Replace("https", "http")
```

Comment: Nice, well done, you solved my problem in less than 2 minutes,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use following code (`Debug` clauses omitted for readability):

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If TextBox11.Text.ToLower.Contains("https") Then
        TextBox11.Text = TextBox11.Text.ToLower.Replace("https", "http")
    End If
    ListBox3.Items.Add(TextBox11.Text.ToLower)
End Sub
```

Let's disseminate code changes a bit:

- `ToLower` method makes sure user didn't enter value using capitalized letters.
- `TextBox11.Text = TextBox11.Text.ToLower.Replace("https", "http")` is the correct way of assigning corrected value to your `TextBox` object.
- Change of `If...End If` structure is understandable - you're about to fill `ListBox` object regardless if `TextBox` value was corrected or not.